# Google App Engine 1.6 available through Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

When I run my GAE dev server, I get the following:

```
   [WARN] ********************************************************
There is a new version of the SDK available.
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.6.0
Timestamp: Mon Oct 17 19:46:22 EDT 2011
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.5.5
Timestamp: Fri Oct 07 21:15:30 EDT 2011
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Please visit http://code.google.com/appengine for the latest SDK.
********************************************************
```

When I go to Help >> Check For Updates, it doesn't find any updates to the Google Eclipse plugin. When I go to Help >> Install New Software, and choose the Google Eclipse Plugin, it says the most recent version of GAE is 1.5.5.

Am I doing something wrong, or have they just not updated it for Eclipse yet?

Answer (score 0):

Open up the GoogleAppEngineLauncher, and it will ask you to update.  Do so, then make any symlinks.  Then reopen Eclipse.  This should update your version of GAE.

Comment: Where can I find GoogleAppEngineLauncher? (I'm on Windows, btw.)

Comment: And where can I find it on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

GoogleAppEngineLauncher is for the Python SDK, not the Java one. The update is not yet available via the Eclipse plugin: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6334 but you can install it manually if don't want to wait an update of the plugin: http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing.html.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the basic instructions for [Installing the Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Installing_the_Google_Plugin_for_Eclipse). Eclipse will recognise that GAE is already installed, and perform an upgrade instead.

You then have to tell eclipse with App Engine SDK to use. You can either set it for just one project (open the Properties window and set under "Google" > "App Engine") or for all of Eclipse (same process, from the Eclipse preferences menu).